# allow semi colons in javascript eslint

Tags: javascript, build, eslint

I have following `.eslintrc`

```
{
    "extends": "standard"
}
```

I have following code in my javascript file

```
import React from 'react';
```

Above line of code is incorrect according to eslint. It gives following complain.

```
";                     Extra semicolon
```

How can I allow semi colons in eslint?

Comment: Standard JS is well-known for omitting semicolons. Why do you want to add them if you're using Standard?

Answer (score 179):

[`eslint-config-standard`](https://github.com/feross/eslint-config-standard/blob/v6.2.1/eslintrc.json#L134) uses the following rule for semicolons:

```
"semi": [2, "never"]
```

The [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) for the rule lists its options:

> - `"always"` (default) requires semicolons at the end of statements
> - `"never"` disallows semicolons as the end of statements (except to disambiguate statements beginning with `[`, `(`, `/`, `+`, or `-`

To overide the rule, you could modify your `.eslintrc` to always require semicolons:

```
{
    "extends": "standard",
    "rules": {
        "semi": [2, "always"]
    }
}
```

Or to disable the rule:

```
{
    "extends": "standard",
    "rules": {
        "semi": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me different if I change from 2 to 1. thanks

Comment: 2 marks it as an error and 1 as a warning, see https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-custom-formatters#the-message-object

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @TobiasFeil . You're right, but the doc page you referenced seems to describe the *output* of eslint, not the inbound configuration of eslint rules.   I had to search "Working with Rules" to find a parenthetical remark that reads "The 2 is the error level" without further elaboration. https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules-deprecated#working-with-rules

Comment: I found this link that is definitive: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

Comment: for me warn option did great in package.json

Answer (score 29):

Modify your `.eslintrc` (deprecated) or `.eslintrc.js`(recommended) with

```
{
    "extends": "standard",
    "rules": {
        "semi": [1, "always"]
    }
}
```

Good Luck...

Comment: The property names need to be double-quoted.

Comment: You wrote `.eslintrc.js` but did you mean `.eslintrc.json`?

Comment: @Wyck When you set up your configuration file, the file type can be YAML, JS, or JSON.