# ESLint Angular rules not working with default configuration

Tags: angular, eslint, typescript-eslint

I've migrated an Angular 14 project from tslint to eslint with these steps:

```
 ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
 ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint myproject
```

in VsCode if I remove a semicolon or I changed `===` to `==` or `=` there is no warning shown

If I add semicolon rule `"semi": [2, "always"]` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453894/allow-semi-colons-in-javascript-eslint)

I see in VsCode:  `Missing semicolon. eslint(semi)[Ln 10,Col 12]`

Do I have to manually add all possible rules in  `.eslintrc.json` file?

default eslintrc.json content :

```
  {
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "semi": [2, "always"], // added by me
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case",
            "type": "element"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase",
            "type": "attribute"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```